# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "(int, int)" в "int" C#

Tags: c#

Я начал изучать C# пару дней назад и столкнулся с вот такой проблемой.

```
public static int[] Score(bool check, int player, int pc) {
    int[] score = { (check == true) ? (player += 1, pc -= 1) : (player -= 1, pc += 1) };
    return score;
}
```

Мой IDE выдает ошибку `Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "(int, int)" в "int"`.
Я также попробовал вот такой метод решения проблемы:

```
public static int[] Score(bool check, int player, int pc) {
    int[] score = (check == true) ? (new int[player += 1, pc -= 1]) : (new int[player -= 1, pc += 1]);
    return score;
}
```

Но этот способ также не хотел работать (`Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int[*,*]" в "int[]"`).

Что делать?

Comment: `{ (check == true) ? (player += 1, pc -= 1) : (player -= 1, pc += 1) };` - это массив кортежей, а вам надо вернуть массив int

Answer (score 1):

Изучить разницу между кортежами `(a,b)` и разными видами массивов (`type[]` - одномерный, `type[,]` - многомерный и `type[][]` - ступенчатый). В вашем случае одномерный массив, который создается следующим образом:

```
int[] score = (check == true) ? 
    new int[] { player += 1, pc -= 1 } : 
    new int[] { player -= 1, pc += 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

int[] - одномерный однотипный массив, вы пытаетесь записать в него кортеж (int player, int pc)
Так нельзя, это разные типы.

Думаю что в вашем случае подойдёт следующий вариант:

```
public static (int player, int pc) Score(bool check, int player, int pc) {
    (int player, int pc) score = check == true ? (player += 1, pc -= 1) : (player -= 1, pc += 1);
    return score;
}
(int player, int pc) a = Score(true, 2, 2); // <-- Вызывать так.
```

Или более продвинутый вариант, где ответа нет, а есть просто изменение значения:

```
public static void Score(bool check, ref int player, ref int pc)
{ // <-- ref получает ссылку на значение, а не его копию, и меняет его там-же, откуда производится вызов функции
   if (check == true) { player += 1; pc -= 1; } else { player -= 1; pc += 1; };
}
///
int player = 2;
int pc = 2;
Score(true, ref player, ref pc);
```

В данном случае метод Score ничего не вернёт, а изменит значения player и pc прям в том месте, откуда производился вызов функции (ref  при передаче указывать обязательно)

Если вам нужно всё-таки возвращать и не кортеж, советую разобраться с структурами, может это то, что вам нужно.